# How to wait for asynchronous wcf calls to finish to use the results?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, task

I need to make two wcf calls to buildup a model

```
[SecurityOperationBehavior]
public Response1 Func1(Request1 req)
{
}


[SecurityOperationBehavior]
public Response2 Func2(Request2 req)
{
}
```

I understand I need to use TaskCompletionSource to wait until both the calls to be finished.

```
public FullResult GetResult(int id)
{
  Request1 req = new Request1 ();
  req.id = id;

  Request2 req2 = new Request2 ();
  req2.id = id;

  var taskCompletions = new[]
                         {
                            new TaskCompletionSource<object>(),
                            new TaskCompletionSource<object>()

                           };
 var tasks = new[] { taskCompletions[0].Task, taskCompletions[1].Task  };

  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Func1(req );
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Func2(req2 );

  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(tasks);

   //the following is what I want to do. The results of the 
   //two service calls will be contained in the the full result

    FullResult  result = new FullResult();

   result.first = tasks[0].Result;
   result.second = tasks[0].Result;

   return Result;



}
```

Problem:

How do I set the results after both the service calls are finished?

Comment: First off, you almost certainly don't want to put `_absClient.QueryAlarmAsync` inside of start new.  You don't need to start an async task in another thread.  Second, what's the signature of `QueryAlarmAsync`?  Does it return a task, does it accept a callback, do the `Request` objects have an event that is fired or a callback property?  There needs to be some mechanism of notifying you when the async operation finishes.

Comment: So, based on your edit, are `Func1` and `Func2` long running *blocking* operations?

Comment: @Servy, sorry, it is Func1 and Func2 I need to call. Updated the question. Please re-read.

Comment: long running-yes. Blocking, No.

Comment: Then how do you know when they're done?  Do the request objects have a callback/event/task that they expose?  That's not something we can know; we'd need to see the definitions of the related types to see what they expose.

Comment: @Servy. What I meant to say is it the functions are blocking on its own, but I want to run it in parallel.

Comment: If the functions are blocking then you shouldn't say they aren't blocking...

Comment: fair point. my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for task completion sources at all here.  Just wait on the results of `Task.StartNew`:

```
public FullResult GetResult(int id)
{
    Request1 req = new Request1();
    req.id = id;

    Request2 req2 = new Request2();
    req2.id = id;

    var tasks = new Task[] {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Func1(req))
        , Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Func2(req2))};

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    FullResult result = new FullResult();

    result.first = tasks[0];
    result.second = tasks[1];

    return result;
}
```